# Thruk - Scripted Dashboard - get params from query string

Tags: perl, thruk

Is it possible to get query string in scripted dashboard ?

I tried to use `CGI` `perl` module in scripted dashboard, but with no success.

The idea is to use scripted dashboard as template to generate thruk maps on the fly by using query params.

Comment: Would have loved to have helped, but your question is unclear and incomplete..

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible right now, but might be in future versions. It might be a bit tricky because there can be multiple dashboard opened at once which all have different parameters.